# grails database-migration - generates a changelog even when no domain model changes

Tags: grails, database-migration

We want to use the database-migration facilities to implement DB schema changes in our UAT and live systems, via our Jenkins(Hudson) build servers.

The simplest approach would be to run "-Dgrails.env=uat dbm-gorm-diff changelog-.xml --add" each time. However, my trials show that an 'empty' changelog is always created and changelog-master.xml updated, even when there are no changes in the domain model. This is not ideal.

Is there an option that I have not found, that says: "only create a changelog when the domain model has changed"?

Otherwise, it looks as though I will have to put steps into the Ant build script to look for a  entry in the changelog-.xml file, and if not found: delete the file and restore the master changelog from a backup, or edit it to remove latest 'include' entry.

If anyone has other good ideas, they would be very welcome.

Regards, John

Comment: What version of the plugin?

Comment: version 1.2.2. This is the latest version the GGTS finds via its plugin manager. Is the facility I'd like in the latest 1.3.2? Ah! I have just discovered (remembered?) that I have to explicitly refresh via the plugin-manager to find any later versions. i have just got 1.3.2.

Comment: Does 1.3.2 behave the same way?

Comment: Errm... no. Instead of an 'empty' changelog-02, it's full of statements that drop all of the columns in my two tables and their link table. I don't understand why this has happened. Is it a bug? I have double-checked. I can see the databasechangelog table in the DB, and its contents show the initial entries from dbsync, and one entry from when I added a column to one of the tables. 

My two domain objects are unchanged. I've just started a run-app for the uat env and everything is in order. I know it's using the same DB, as my first launch failed because I had forgotten to close the DB connctn

Comment: Burt. I have just noticed that DdmGormDiff.groovy has changed between 1.2.2 and 1.3.2, so different behaviour likely. 

I am testing my little brain to destruction, trying to understand how to write a Gant script. I had it open in Notepad++ as a possible useful example of how to write a Gant script (I want a script to invoke DbmGormdiff with parms to call from Jenkins, along with test-app and war). When I updated the plugin, I allowed the deleted file to stay open. Which is why I can see the changes, though, as yet, not able to really understand the code.
John

Comment: Burt. BTW, I have just come across a report of a bug found for DbmGormDiff giving errors in 1.3.2 after upgrade from 1.2.1. So, I guess there are some problems introduced. i'll try 1.3.1. See:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120?focusedCommentId=73677&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Comment: Burt. FWIW The same problem is in 1.3 and 1.3.1 - looks like same code is in DbmGormDiff.groovy. I have reverted to 1.2.2, but now that fails with a MissingMethodException. Such is  life...

Comment: If you can create a small project that demonstrates the problem please create a JIRA issue and I'll take a look. Run `grails bug-report` and attach the generated zip

Comment: I tried using a copy of my 'problem' project. This did not repeat the error. Instead, dbm-* commands displayed the 'started' message. but never the 'ended', and just died. I will investigate further, now that I am over my initial scripting 'hump'

Comment: Try adding `--stacktrace` and optionally `--verbose` so you see any exceptions. They're probably in `target/stacktrace.log` now though.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid :

grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.dataSourceNameWithSuffix() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null] at

You don't have to make all this things with changing project name etc. you only need to clear

"path_to_user_dir"/.grails/projects/"project_name"/scriptCache directory

Answer (score 0):

Installing 1.3.2 seems to have added something somewhere that isn't removed when the plugin is removed. Sorry, not a very scientific description, but that's how it appears.

I'm now back at 1.2.2, but no matter what dbm-* script I run, I get the same error:

======================

Error Error executing script DbmGenerateGormChangelog: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.dataSourceNameWithSuffix() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null] (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.dataSourceNameWithSuffix() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:37)
    at DbmGenerateGormChangelog$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGenerateGormChangelog:23)
Error Error executing script DbmGenerateGormChangelog: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.dataSourceNameWithSuffix() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]

==============

I have removed 1.3.2, restated GGTS then installed earlier versions, even going back to 1.2.1, before returbning to 1.2.2, but no change. Looks like I might have to try with a new workspace, to see if I can get 1.2.2 to work again.
Rgds, John

Comment: FYI. Exported app, removed dbm plugin, renamed app and closed GGTS. Opened GGTS with a new workspace, imported app, added dbm plugin 1.2.2. Now I can run the dbm-* scripts as before.